# why is this beginner java program have a error

Tags: java

I've started to learn java and was coding this for some practice. please tell me where I went wrong, it says I have  an illegal start of expression on line 27.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class steps
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Scanner Keyboard =  new Scanner(System.in);
        print("What is your name?");
        String name = Keyboard.nextLine();
        print("What is five + five?");
        String number = Keyboard.nextLine();
        String gj = (", Good Job");

        switch (number){
            case "ten":
                print("correct" + gj + (" ") + name);
                break;
            case "Ten":
                print("correct" + gj +(" ") + name);
                break;
            case "10":
                print("correct" + gj +(" ") + name);
                break;
            default:
                print("Wroung try again");
        }

        static void print(String s) {  // <--- this is line 27
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
// <--- there is no trailing } here?
```

Comment: Your function print doesn't need to be static. just `void print (String s){} will do.

Comment: ps: If you found your answer, make sure to click on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count your opening and closing curly braces -- you're off.You are missing a closing brace, and due to that, it looks like you're declaring a method inside of another method.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot define a method inside a method in Java, move this code out of your `main()` method:

```
 static void print(String s){
      System.out.println(s);
  }
```

Also look at your braces carefully, this is where clear indention of codes will help.

Answer (score 2):

**nested methods** are not allowed in java.**Nested methods** means methods inside another method.In your case `print` method is contained inside `main` method which is not allowed.

do like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class steps
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
         Scanner Keyboard =  new Scanner(System.in);
        print("What is your name?");
        String name = Keyboard.nextLine();
          print("What is five + five?");
        String number = Keyboard.nextLine();
        String gj = (", Good Job");

      switch (number){
          case "ten":
              print("correct" + gj + (" ") + name);
              break;
          case "Ten":
              print("correct" + gj +(" ") + name);
              break;
          case "10":
              print("correct" + gj +(" ") + name);
              break;
          default:
              print("Wroung try again");
      }


   }
    static void print(String s){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

probably what you meant to have was one more closing curly brace *just before* line 27 so that the `static void print(String s)` would not be *inside* the `public static void main(String []args)`

Answer (score 0):

Static doesn't and should not go into main. You can call your print method inside of main by calling it like this `print("String printed");`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class steps {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is your name? ");
    String name = Keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("What is five + five? ");
    String number = Keyboard.nextLine();
    String gj = (", Good Job");

    switch (number) {
    case "ten":
        System.out.print("correct" + gj + (" ") + name);
        break;
    case "Ten":
        System.out.print("correct" + gj + (" ") + name);
        break;
    case "10":
        System.out.print("correct" + gj + (" ") + name);
        break;
    default:
        while (Integer.parseInt(number)!= 10){//Checks if number isn't correct
            //and ask user to input again until he gets it right.
        System.out.print("Wrong try again :");
         number = Keyboard.nextLine();
         if(Integer.parseInt(number)==10){
                System.out.print("correct" + gj + (" ") + name)

         }

        }
    }
    print("String printed");

}

static void print(String s) { 
    System.out.println("\n"+s);
   }
}
```